# Is it possible to map a type to an integer?

Tags: c++

Consider the following struct:

```
struct value{
    std::vector<UCHAR> raw_data;
    int type;
};
```

Lets say the value of ***type*** can be { 0, 1, 2 } for this example.

If type == 0 then the data in the vector is representing a 4byte signed integer

If type == 1 then the data in the vector is representing a 2byte signed integer

If type == 2 then the data in the vector is an array of raw bytes of arbitrary length

The format of the structure is out of my control and there are over 30 possible values of ***type***.

Is it possible to determine the type at runtime?  Perhaps something like this pseudo code:

```
void PrintValue(value & v)
{
    TypeLookup<v.type> val(v); // Assuming the type is supported by cout
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

What I am currently doing is a large switch statment anytime I use value then calling the apropriate conversion method eg:

```
int32_t GetValAs32Integer();
int16_t GetValAsShort();
std::vector<UCHAR> GetValAsRaw();
```

Is there a more eligant way to do this?

Comment: Are you in control of the types that can be stored? Are these class types?

Comment: Maybe use a union in place of the vector?

Comment: "The format of the structure is out of my control"

Comment: You could consider a visitor pattern. Rather than extracting the value and use it, pass a generic Callable to the `value` which dispatches on its underlying type and calls the function with its concrete value. Kind of like what is used in C++17's `std::visit` with `std::variant` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Comment: @KABoissonneault I'll look into that, thanks!

Comment: @user3853544 I understood *"The format of the structure is out of my control"* to mean the format of `value`. Did you also mean for that statement to cover the types of the values that could be assigned to `value`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes that is correct.  All possible types are primitives of various sizes or byte arrays or strings (including wstring).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more eligant way to do this?

No. A switch over `type` is as elegant as this gets. And given that you only have to handle 3 values, it should be elegant enough.

Comment: This example only shows 3 in practise it is over 30 possible types.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't really do this. There is no "type" variable that allows you to pass a type to a function. However templates give you virtually all the functionality you require, other than the ability to switch on the type of a variable at runtime. You can specialise a template, and you can create "auto" variables which hold any type (but ultimately derived from either templates or types directly aded to sourcecode).

If you find you need dynamic typing in C++, the best answer is to move up a level. Create or get from the web a JSON (Javascript object notation) parser / wrapper, and pass the dynamic variables around in that. Then you can query for fields and for their type, so it's possible to have an "employee" with or without a "title" field, if say customs in one country are different from customs in another and some place omit the "Mr" whilst others insist on it.